# swift - get value from string using regular expression

Tags: ios, swift, regex, string

I want to extract a value from a string in swift 4.

I tried to use regular expression but it didn't work all i want is to extract the PK value from this query:

```
"INSERT INTO table(PK,anotherValue) VALUES ('38061','1233')"
```

I want the result here to be: 38061

the regex i tried:

```
   var results = [String]()
    do{
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern:" VALUES ('(.*?)'", options: [])
    regex.enumerateMatches(in: query, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, query.utf16.count)) { result, flags, stop in
        if let r = result?.range(at: 1), let range = Range(r, in: query) {
            results.append(String(query[range]))
        }
    }
    } catch {
       print( error)
    }
    print(results)
```

i got below error :

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The value “ VALUES
>   ('(.*?)'” is invalid." UserInfo={NSInvalidValue= VALUES ('(.*?)'

Answer (score 5):

The parentheses are special characters for capturing groups.

To treat a parenthesis as literal character you have to escape it:

```
pattern:" VALUES \\('(.*?)'"
```

Please look at:
https://regex101.com/r/lyzoex/1